# SQL Developer Changes Table and Column Names to Uppercase

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm learning how to use the current version of Oracle's SQL Developer, however I'm having some issues with the software. Whenever I try to create a new table or edit an existing one, the software automatically changes the table and column names to all uppercase. I would prefer to keep the table and column names in camel case. The worksheet formatting is fine, just not the table editor. Is there a way to change this setting?

Comment: I have never seen it in camelCase it has always been ALLCAPS for me. It might just be an Oracle thing.

Comment: Oracle stores unquoted names in upper case this complies with the requirements of the SQL standard. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 1):

You can force Oracle to use mixed-case identifiers by surrounding your table and column names in double quotes.

```
CREATE TABLE "myTable" (
  "thisIsAColumn" integer,
  "thisIsAnotherColumn" varchar2(50)
);
```

However, you really ought not do this.  If you do, then every reference to your table and your column will be case-sensitive and will need to use the same double-quoted identifier.  That is, you'd need to do

```
SELECT "thisIsAColumn", "thisIsAnotherColumn"
  FROM "myTable"
```

This sort of thing generally gets annoying quickly particularly when SQL and PL/SQL are generally not case-sensitive languages.  Future developers that have to maintain your code will likely find it annoying to constantly have to double-quote identifiers and to have to get the case correct when queries against other tables remain case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

I think this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm) for you.

The following examples are valid schema object names:

```
last_name
horse
hr.hire_date
"EVEN THIS & THAT!"
a_very_long_and_valid_name
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.